# How to create a Grafana Email Alert notification for a prometheus metric?

Tags: node.js, monitoring, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a Prometheus data source, that has a counter metric for failed requests, I want to send email alert notifications whenever the metric is non-zero?

I am using [prom-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prom-client) to generate the metrics

Comment: https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#email_config

Answer (score 0):

Steps to set up a Email Notification in Grafana.

1. Understand how the Grafana is configured [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/#configuration).
2. Configure [SMTP settings](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/#smtp) in Grafana to enable it to send emails.Local SMTP can be set up to test [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-20-04).
3. Set up Notification Alerts by following [this](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/notifications/#alert-notifications).
4. Create [alerts](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/create-alerts/)